# object HTMLInputElement being sent instead of value by AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi I am fairly new to AJAX but I am trying to send a value from an input field that is being altered. The field is part of a table that is dynamcially built from a MySQL database. Once the field is altered a function is fired that sends the values to a PHP file. While all the other values are being sent my problem is that when I send the *input* field it means my database adds [object HTMLInputElement] instead of the value I wanted.

My code for my table is....

```
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td><?php echo $row['idcpu']; ?></td>
    <?php 
    echo "<td> <input type=\"text\" onblur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'name','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\" value=\"".$row['name']."\" /> </td>";
    echo "<td> <textarea onblur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'description','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\" >".$row['description']."'</textarea></td>";
    echo "<td> <textarea onblur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'price','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\"></textarea>".$row['price']."</td>";
    echo "<td> <textarea onblur=\"saveToDatabase(this,'quantity','".$row['idcpu']."');\" onClick=\"showEdit(this);\"></textarea>".$row['quantity']."</td>"; ?>
  </tr>
```

And my javascript function that send the information.....

```
function sendToPHP(editableObj,column,id) {
  $.ajax({
          url: "update/cpu.php",
          type: "POST",
          data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj+'&id='+id,
          success: function(data){
                   $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
                   }
  });
}
```

I have tried to use `document.getElementById` so I can retrieve the value and I couldn't get it to work but I was hoping to keep my code so that it can work for each part of the table. I wish to make every cell able to use this script. Could somebody give some advice?

Comment: you want the `value` property

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you